# using resource dictionaries in Expression Blend to handle light/dark themes in WP

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I wrote a custom [ResourceDictionary](http://blog.richardszalay.com/2011/06/11/practical-support-for-light-dark-themes-on-windows-phone-7/) that implements theme support in the exact same way: by loading the appropriate theme dictionary depending on the light/dark theme.

```
 <ApplicationName:ThemeResourceDictionary.LightResources>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/ApplicationName;component/Resources/Light.xaml"/>
</ApplicationName:ThemeResourceDictionary.LightResources>

<ApplicationName:ThemeResourceDictionary.DarkResources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/ApplicationName;component/Resources/Dark.xaml"/>
</ApplicationName:ThemeResourceDictionary.DarkResources>
```

Stylr file:

```
<ResourceDictionary  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"       
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">    
<BitmapImage x:Key="Logo62"  UriSource="/ApplicationName;component/icon_62_dark.png" />
```

On my XAML page I use it like

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource Logo62}" Margin="0,4,10,0"/>
```

when I run the application all works well but in Expression Bland i have an error: 
"The resource "Logo62" could not be resolved" and I do not see this image.
Could anybody help me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your resource dictionary to this:

```
<ResourceDictionary  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"       
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">    
<BitmapImage x:Key="Logo62"  UriSource="/icon_62_dark.png" />
```

Note that I removed the /ApplicationName;component/

Otherwise you'll have to **change** the image **build action** in Visual Studio to **Resource** instead of Content, otherwise the file won't be build and included in the project correctly.